# UIWebView performance with JS onclick function

Tags: javascript, ios, performance, uiwebview

I have a rather large page showing in a UIWebView (around 150 `<article>s` with some text, separated in `<section>s`). I want to do something like this with JS (I use jQuery):

```
$('article').click(function() {alert('hi');});
```

The problem is, it takes forever to run that code (around 2 seconds from the tap, on an iPad 3).

**How can I improve performance on this?**

I'm using the latest version of XCode and iOS 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513002/368864)'s class `SingleTapDetector`, and the following code:

```
new SingleTapDetector(window, function(e) {
  alert($(e.srcElement).text()); //show the text of the element that was tapped
});
```

Then it's easy to see if the element was an `article`, or even stuff like `$(e.srcElement).closest('article')` (because my articles have `<p>` paragraphs).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try to put a click event on the window object, and then verify if this is the `<article>` tag. Here's the example:

```
$(window).click(function(e){
    var e = e || event;
    if(e.srcElement.tagName==ARTICLE)
        alert('hi');
});
```

Comment: It's not working at all with this code.. I tried this too: `function(e) {alert(e.srcElement.tagName);}`, nothing, not even an empty alert...